# Boolean hashCode return value

Tags: java, boolean, hashcode

Why Boolean hashCode is either 1231 or 1237? i.e.

```
public static int hashCode(boolean value) {
        return value ? 1231 : 1237;
    }
```

any specific reason? 
We are passing String value "true" or "false" in the Boolean constructor so why not we are using the hashcode of these Strings("true" and "false") itself? or we can use 0 and 1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question?

Comment: A boolean only has 2 possible values `true` and `false` the hashcode for `true` will be the same in the same execution and the hashcode for `false` will be the same within the same execution...

Comment: @brso05 Actually it will always be the same, as specified in its API documentation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's fine I am just talking about the `HashCode` specification (set of rules/contract) I didn't realize they had a specific rule for booleans...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If you look at my statement it is technically correct ;) it will always be the same in the same execution...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#hashCode()

Comment: @brso05 "Today Earth is a planet" is another _technically_ correct statement.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes you are correct nice!